# Manipulating Redux output

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a React application to render content of a WordPress website using the WordPress Rest API, Redux and Thunk.

The WordPress API returns posts without detailed information about the category (`name`, `slug`, etc). All I'm getting is the `id`. I'm currently calling an additional action/function to get the detailed category information ([output](https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/879a7c35867dfd862a26da519bc32f53)). Below an example of how I'm currently fetching my posts.

```
// Actions.js

import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchPosts = (page = 1) => {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_POSTS",
    payload: axios.get(`${REST_URL}/wp/v2/posts?per_page=14&page=${page}`)
  }
}
```

|

```
// PostsReducer.js
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null
}

export default function reducer(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_POSTS": {
      return {
        ...state, 
        fetching: true
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_POSTS_REJECTED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    }
    case "FETCH_POSTS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        posts: action.payload
      }
    }
  }

  return state
}
```

And this is how I'm fetching category information:

```
export const fetchCategory = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_CATEGORY",
    payload: axios.get(`${REST_URL}/wp/v2/categories/${id}`)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to combine my `fetchPosts()` action with the `fetchCategory()` action, so it populates the `post.categories`, returned from `fetchPosts()` with the more detailed `fetchCategory()` information?

Comment: do you mean ajax call chaining?

Comment: I would look into normalizing your state using something like normalizr. Working with arrays in Redux is really painful and flattening your state tree will make management a breeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring for ajax calls chaining you can use this example to understand how `thunk` can work for you:

```
function loadSomeThings() {
    return dispatch => {
        fetchFirstThingAsync.then(data => { // first API call
            dispatch({ type: 'FIRST_THING_SUCESS', data }); // you can dispatch this action if you want to let reducers take care of the first API call
            return fetchSecondThingAsync(data), // another API call with the data received from the first call that returns a promise
        })
        .then(data => {
             dispatch({ type: 'SECOND_THING_SUCESS', data }); // the reducers will handle this one as its the object they are waiting for
        });
    };
}
```

Basically when we call `loadSomeThings` we dispatch an new `action` as a function (`fetchFirstThingAsync`) as our first ajax call, `redux-thunk` will catch that before any reducer does as function are not the plain object that reducers can handle, `thunk` will invoke this `function` with `dispatcher` as an argument (along `getState` and some more `args`), we wait it out with `.then` and then we can dispatch a plain object that `reducers` can handle + returning another promise (`fetchSecondThingAsync`) that's your second ajax call, we wait it out with `.then` and again dispatching a plain object that reducers can handle.

Comment: Thanks @Sag1v. Problem with this is that reducers would output it as two different items in my store, right? `FIRST_THING` would include the posts and `SECOND_THING` would include the categories. `FIRST_THING` would be an object containing all the posts in my case with a 'categories' child. The detailed categories, which would be the second dispatch in your example, need to be added to the categories children of the first dispatch, handled by the `FIRST_THING` reducer.

Comment: I was thinking to populate an object variable in the first dispatch and manipulate it in the second. Then create a third dispatch to return it all to a reducer. I'm not sure if that's the way to go, since I'm working with a variable and also wouldn't know how to write this while keeping the Redux syntax in mind.

Comment: @BobWassermann thats the thing, you dont have to dispatch the plain object in the first API call eg: `FIRST_THING_SUCESS` and reducers wont handle functions but `thunk` will. you can read this nice article about `redux-think` that can make it more clear on how it works http://blog.jakoblind.no/2017/04/25/async-actions-with-redux-thunk-demystified/

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I think I'm still doing something wrong. read the blogpost, but am still not sure how this would look with reducers. I modified my code to the following: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/8b482258500e2caabfc671d0fabc1278

Comment: Worked it out. Updated the gist with working code. Thanks @Sag1v